# How to generate the 3D model based on iPhone TrueDepth Camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, 3d

Here is a problem I am thinking, Can we just use the demo Apple give us to get the depth data from the camera and use the depth data we have to generate a 3D model of this?

the core problem is how could I extract depth data from iPhone, is there a demo or sample code for the present?  just print it out is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you start with what Apple provided from [WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/)?  There are multiple examples with source code there such as [Using Depth Data](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Using-Depth-Data.zip).

Comment: I've looked about that, and the presentation said depth map does not work well on the 3d scene reconstruction since the depth map color only have 8 bit, it's not good enough to represent depth information

Answer (score 0):

You can only 3D-model simple surfaces or objects less than 1 meter away from the phone. The distance and accuracy are upper-bounded by both the 3D camera's noise floor, and the color depth (8-bit currently).